# Decent Git Branch Visualization tool

Tags: git, git-gui

I'm using git for a personal and big project which has a wide scope (not just programming) and lots of file. Hence I've a lot of branches and merges and I want to have a nice visualization tool for branches and merges in Git (esp. if it offer an animation just like **Gource** or graph capability like **PlasticSCM**).
gitk or git log are nice tools and I'm currently using them but not the solution I want.

I like open source projects, and I prefer an application which just do the job (not a whole git front-end) however if there is no open source solutions, closed ones or heavy git softwares are welcomed.
I've find:

**SeeGitApp** (Not good for me, esp for a long and heavy branch and merging),

**GitCola** (I couldn't install it on windows in the first try),

**GitVersionTree** (very basic),

**gitlist** (server based, php, I couldn't try it),

**gittreemap**,

**git2html.sh**,

**git log --pretty**.

As I said, I've just searched for open source and utilities. if there isn't such utility for this task what would you offer instead?

Comment: Looks like the requester DID describe the problem and what other tools were tried as solutions. The requester did not ask "what is the best?". The question was, "are there any that resolve this situation and what might they be?"

It seems that the set of answers is small, and NO SPAM WAS OFFERED.

Comment: Git Kraken can be a good solution. You can use the free version to experience it. https://www.gitkraken.com/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about [ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit)?

[image: Ungit Screenshot]

Ungit can be a bit tricky to install if you're not familiar with Node.js, but IMO it's the best git GUI I've seen so far.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I'm trying it now and It's cool! I like it. (The nodes in the graph are a bit small but there should be a way). It reminds me Sublime Text (another love):D

Comment: Currently, ungit is my choice but I like to see more option if possible. BTW, is there a way to resize the node in the graph? I mean smaller nodes?

Comment: @ToX Hmm, I don't know I've never had to do that before. Maybe try using your browser's zoom functionality? (`Ctrl`+`Scroll` or `Ctrl`+`+` / `Ctrl`+`-`.)

If that doesn't work, you could always submit an issue. Ungit's author has been really good so far about responding to user feedback.

Comment: Had some success with this, doesn't seem to like every repo though. Lots and lots of outstanding issues not resolved also.

Comment: Ungit also has a nice plugin for VS Code. [link](https://github.com/RomanValihura/vscode-ungit-tab)

Comment: osx `brew install ungit`

Answer (score 20):

Stock `gitk --all` or, at the console:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

(I have this call aliased to `git overview`, by the way).  To get better results with the display consider setting the `color.ui` Git configuration variable to `auto`.

Comment: Normally I'd recommend the same thing, but the OP specifically said "gitk or git log are nice tools and I'm currently use them but not the exact solution".

Comment: @Ajedi32, yes, but I assumed the OP is unaware of the `--all` command-line option of `gitk` and the `--graph` mode of `git log` which really provide a different picture to "the usual" way of invoking these tools.

Comment: @Ajedi32, I even have a fellow developer here at my $dayjob who never ever calls `gitk` without the `--all` command-line option ;-)

Comment: Yup. Personally, I've got `git lg` aliased to `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` and I frequently tack the `--all` option onto that when I want to get a overview of the whole repo.

Comment: @kostix, I'm aware of log -all :D and this is my personal alias if you like:
KuLog = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %C(dim white)%s %C(green)(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative

p.s. I've lots of branch (not very usual in software dev). gitk --all is almost useless here.

Comment: `gitg --all` seems to also be a nice way to inspect things.  Style differences as usual between k and g things.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a cool Git GUI tool that I've been using in the past - [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed it. Log View is cool but I think it has two problem for me: 1) being closed source 2) Log View presentation of graph is same as gitk or git log. I prefer more detailed graph. SmartGit and GitEye are also equivalent

Comment: I love this tool but i don't understand why it is free formac os x but not free on windows =)

Comment: It is free in Windows. Been using it for about a year and a half. Requires registration though.