# How to customise UnGit branch graph?

Tags: git, version-control, smartgit, git-gui, gitk

I'm using ungit for visualize branches and merges in my project. I don't use git just for the programming purposes and there are a lot of branching and merging. Currently I've tested some apps from **git log** and **gitk** to **Source Tree**. (please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116069/decent-git-branch-visualization-tool)).

However I like to know if it would be possible to easily adjust and customize nodes and branches in the graph below. I know it is technically possible but I'm not familiar with CSS or js and etc. However I like to learn new tools as far as they provide straight solution for this problem. I've the option to submit a request to ungit developer but I want to know possible home remedies before hand.

here is an example of git tree:

[image: a simple test example for ungit graph]